# To limit upload filesize before uploading with php://input

Tags: php, app-inventor

How make to detect filesize of file to upload and limit filesize.I use this code.

```
 $fname=$_GET['filename'];
 $data=file_get_contents('php://input');
 if(file_put_contents($fname,$data)==true)){
   echo"$fname is uploaded.";
 }else{
   echo"fail";
 }
```

I use appinventor app and ftp sever.

Comment: Well, `$data` is a variable of which you can determine the size; just checking `$_SERVER['CONTENT_SIZE']` is a better idea, though.

Comment: please write a code contained that you say.Please.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents reads a file into a string. So you can get the size of a string in a variety of ways. Here are a few:

Get the amount of characters in a string:

```
strlen($string)
```

Get the amount of words in a string:

```
str_word_count($string)
```

You can also get the amount of memory PHP has allocated to store the string with:

```
$start_memory = memory_get_usage();
$data=file_get_contents('php://input');
echo memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
```

Comment: The latter two pieces of information aren't applicable to the question at all.